# When I play streaming media with my iPad,the screen is black but it sounds normal

Tags: iphone, ipad, video-streaming

I find this in device's console:

> Tue Jul 13 13:21:28
>   sumomo-bunketsumigikakkos-iPad
>   com.apple.mediaserverd[83] :
>   vxdDec - Frame# 1395, DecodeFrame
>   failed with error: 305

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend told me that it maybe something wrong in coding/decoding....